# How can I show others a deleted question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

For good or bad reasons, questions can get deleted. Is it possible to show someone a deleted question I posted, if only to prove that difficult questions sometimes get deleted?

Comment: You can create screenshots, so the answer is _yes_.

Comment: I can if I can access the page.

Comment: Post owners can always access their posts.

Comment: How do I find my posts?

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117892/how-do-you-view-deleted-questions

Comment: It's difficult, for good or bad reasons.